# Conception/Delivery Same Time

Tags: sources-mekorot, messiah, pregnancy-birth

What is the source that states when Moshiach is here - women will deliver babies the moment they conceive. I heard this in a shiur from HaRav Yitzchak Ginsburg in Israel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The source is probably [the Talmud (Shabbos 30b)](http://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.30b.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> כי הא דיתיב רבן גמליאל וקא דריש עתידה אשה שתלד בכל יום שנאמר (ירמיהו לא, ח) הרה ויולדת יחדיו
>
> Rabban Gamliel was sitting and he interpreted a verse homiletically:
>   In the future, in the World-to-Come, a woman will give birth every
>   day, as it says: “The woman with child and her that gives birth
>   together” (Jeremiah 31:7), explaining that birth will occur on the
>   same day as conception. (Sefaria)

Comment: Thank you for this answer! The HaRav did not give his source and I have been searching for it!

Comment: @Geula613 you're very welcome!

Comment: @Geula613 If you like this answer best, you can click the check mark next to this answer to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Those who take this idea literally are forced to say that the status of mitzvos will change. Specifically hilchos nida.

Comment: @user6591, that is hyper-literal. You could just understand it to mean that she can give birth every day, and will give birth on the day of conception. Not that she will have 365 children a (solar) year.

Comment: @Yishai This isn't my haara. I saw it recently brought as a proof in that machlokes. And for the record, what you are suggesting is a possible outgrowth of what is actually written. It says they will give birth every day. It never says how long the pregnancy will last. Suggesting they will have one day pregnancies but not every day is taking the taful and leaving the ikur.

Comment: @Yishai I do remember seeing somewhere the suggestion that the gestation period of the children will be more along the lines of chickens who have rows of eggs at different points of development at any given time. But I didn't see this mentioned in the aforementioned machlokes, probably because it wouldn't matter. Pesichas kever would render her tamei even if she was pregnant with a different child at the time.

Comment: How does the Gemara add to the pasuk in terms of answering the question? On the contrary, the pasuk alone seems like more direct support than the Gemara.

Comment: @DovF That's not the plain meaning of the pasuk, even Rabban Gamliel isn't saying it is - it's drush, not pshat. The plain meaning is that it is referring to two different people.

Comment: @user6591, I didn't mean to say it was wrong, just hyper-literal. It would require us to say that Rabban Gamliel expects women to have marital relations every single night of the year, though, otherwise I don't see how it addresses anything WRT the status of Mitzvos.